# cocoa asyncudpsockets don't send bytestream

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, udp, cocoaasyncsocket

I have a little MAC OS X Application that should send a UDP Datagram to a server.

I want to use the cocoa asyncudpsockets (http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) to do this, but i have the problem that i call the "sendData" method but nothing happens.

```
[socket sendData:[NSData dataWithBytes:stream length:length] 
          toHost:host 
            port:(uint16)port 
     withTimeout:5 
             tag:1];
```

stream is a Byte* contains the datagram host is a ip-address as NSString.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does the method return YES or NO?  Did you set up the delegate methods?

Comment: Returns YES, yes i set up the delegate methods, none of them (sent, didntsent) gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you correctly set the delegate ?

```
[socket setDelegate:self];
```

Then :

```
[socket connectToHost:(NSString *)host
               onPort:(UInt16)port
          withTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout
                error:(NSError **)errPtr];
```

Then in the delegate method :

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port
{
    [sock writeData:[NSData dataWithBytes:stream length:length] withTimeout:TIMEOUT_NONE tag:TAG_HEADER];
}
```

Hope it will help ;-)

Comment: This sample code does not deal with error and has to be improve for your software release ;)

Comment: I did sockets = [[AsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self] to set the delegate.
Should be quite the same...
I didn't connect the socket (cause udp is usually connectionless) and used sendData:...
Do i have to connect with the udp sockets too?

Comment: You can try, it mays help. UDP is just a protocol with which you don't care about the information is received successfully. But it is a connection protocol anyway like TCP.

Comment: Thanks i will try that as soon as possilbe